# Is it possible to use Get package for apps that use CupertinoApp()?

Tags: flutter

[GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package readme says:

- Step 1: Add "Get" before your MaterialApp, turning it into
  GetMaterialApp

  void main() => runApp(GetMaterialApp(home: Home()));
- Note: This step in only necessary if you gonna use route management (Get.to(), Get.back() and so on). If you not gonna use it then it is not necessary to do step 1

I'm creating an app for iOS and therefore I use CupertinoApp() widget instead of MaterialApp(). And I want to use route management as well.

Is it possible to use **Get** package for apps that use CupertinoApp() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set "Cupertino like" configs in `Get.config`. E.g. I've made app that uses Cupertino transition

Comment: Can you provide on details. How to do that ? @YerassylMaikhanov

Answer (score 0):

GetX also comes with GetCupertinoApp. You can configure it at the main.dart

```
runApp(
  GetCupertinoApp(
    title: "Application",
    initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL,
    getPages: AppPages.routes,
    locale: Get.deviceLocale,
    translations: Messages(),
    fallbackLocale: const Locale('es', 'ES'),
  ),
);
```